# Failed to pass parameter value from html to php

Tags: php, html, forms

Here, i'm trying to upload file in server. After choosing the file from pc when i submit it i'm getting Undefined index error in those lines of php file where the html parameter values are called. For example in those lines containing "u_file". So, the html parameter value is not passing in php. I can't find why is this happening.

Here goes the html

```
<body>
<div>
    <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <input id="u_file" type="file" name="u_file" size="200000"><br>
        <input type="text" id="tex" name="tex">

        <br />

        <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="submit">

    </form>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the upload.php

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('log_errors', 1);

$u_file = $_POST['u_file'];

$targetfolder = "testupload/";

$targetfolder = $targetfolder . basename( $_FILES['u_file']['name']) ;

$ok=1;

$file_type=$_FILES['u_file']['type'];

if ($file_type=="application/pdf" || $file_type=="image/gif" || $file_type=="image/jpeg") {

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['u_file']['tmp_name'], $targetfolder))

    {

        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['file']['name']). " is uploaded";

    }

    else {

        echo "Problem uploading file";

    }

}

else {

    echo $_POST["u_file"];

}
```

Comment: What does `print_r($_FILES);` say?

Comment: Array ( )  it says.

Comment: `$u_file = $_POST['u_file'];` line is not needed.

Comment: I know it is not needed and removing this line doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it as the problem was something with the IDE where i was coding. I put the whole project in var/www/html folder and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

input type file is cannot be print using $_POST it should be print using $_FILES. Update the code of upload.php

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('log_errors', 1);

$u_file = $_FILES['u_file'];

$targetfolder = "testupload/";

$targetfolder = $targetfolder . basename( $_FILES['u_file']['name']) ;

$ok=1;

$file_type=$_FILES['u_file']['type'];

if ($file_type=="application/pdf" || $file_type=="image/gif" || $file_type=="image/jpeg") {

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['u_file']['tmp_name'], $targetfolder))

    {

        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['u_file']['name']). " is uploaded";

    }

    else {

        echo "Problem uploading file";

    }

}

else {

    print_r($_FILES["u_file"]);

}
?>
```